# Алгоритм нахождения n-ного числа Фибоначчи

Tags: php, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно написать на языке php алгоритм нахождения n-ного числа Фибоначчи, алгоритм должен находить любое число при n<=20000 и находить его за 20 или менее секунд на железе: Core i5-2500 3.3Ghz 4 core 8Gb RAM
Вариант сгенерировать результаты, а потом их выдавать - не походит

Comment: Да, интересная у вас задача, хоть и несложная. А в чём вопрос-то? Вы ведь, конечно, не просите нас реализовать задачу за вас? Тем более, алгоритмы расчёта чисел Фибоначчи, хоть итеративный за `O(n)`, хоть матричный за O(log n) легко гуглятся.

Comment: @wmalex64rf, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: мой алгоритм считает быстрее, чем за секунду. Правда при n = 20000 там около 3000 знаков. Все на чистом php.

Comment: рекурсивный:) но быстрый.

Comment: @igumnov: а трюк с округлением знаете? фактически, `$F_n = round(\tau^n / \sqrt{5})`, где `$\tau = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$`.

Comment: @KoVadim: поделитесь? только плиз псевдокод, ладно?

Comment: ну что, а вдруг Вы перепродадите решение?)

Comment: @KoVadim: убедили :) я не спец в php, так что перепродаст кто-нибудь другой :)

Comment: Да в английской википедии хорошая статья про них, можно еще вычислять как сумму биномиальных коэффициентов в треугольнике Паскаля, наверное это быстрее чем с формулой выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Тест]

Comment: Вы пытались посчитать его при n=20000?

Comment: Я не преобразовывал это в ответ. Это просто нерекурентная формула полученная на основании системы дифференциальных уравнений записанных матричной форме.