# Как найти 12 елемент з Math.pow?

Tags: числа-фибоначчи

Найди двенадцатый элемент (let nFib = 12, el12;) последовательности Леонардо Пизанского (нужно использовать функцию Math.pow(число, степень)). Не забудьте округлить полученное число до целого — Math.round(число).

Comment: это же javascript?

Comment: Это сайт с вопросами о программировании (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). Укажите язык программирования. Что вы пытались сделать для решения задачи? Пытались ли вы искать ответы? Похоже, что ответ есть, например, тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184869/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-n-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

открывайте википедию и читайте про числа Фибоначчи

там же приводится замечательная формула Бине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функции `Math.pow` и `Math.round` вы знаете - осталось совсем немного - закодить эту функцию в 1 строчку